# Replace NAs in numeric vectors with values calculated from neighbours

Tags: r, na

I am trying to write a *replacena()* function which substitutes each missing value in a given numeric vector for an **arithmetic mean** of **its preceding and following element**.

For example, if `c(5, NA, 6, 2, 3, 5, 6, 4, NA, 2, NA, 5)` is given, then the result should be `c(5, 5.5, 6, 2, 3, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2, 3.5, 5)`.

I am searching for some elegant solution, possibly with apply functions (without control-flow constructions), but yet I didn't come up with anything working. I wasn't quite sure how to access the previous and next element in lambda function(x).

```
replacena <- function(l)
{
   stopifnot(is.numeric(l))
   sapply(l[is.na(l)], function(x){ l[x] <- mean( c(l[-1:0], l[0:1]) ) } )
}
```

**Function input:**

```
replacena(c(5, NA, 6, 2, 3, 5, 6, 4, NA, 2, NA, 5))
```

**Expected output**

```
c(5, 5.5, 6, 2, 3, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2, 3.5, 5)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we into reinventing the wheel (see akruns answer), we could achieve this by modifying your function to the following:

```
replacena <- function(l) {
  stopifnot(is.numeric(l))
  indx <- is.na(l)
  l[indx] <- vapply(which(indx), function(x) mean(c(l[x - 1], l[x + 1])), FUN.VALUE = double(1))
  l
}


replacena(c(5, NA, 6, 2, 3, 5, 6, 4, NA, 2, NA, 5))
## [1] 5.0 5.5 6.0 2.0 3.0 5.0 6.0 4.0 3.0 2.0 3.5 5.0
```

Or a vectorized version of your function (without using the `*apply` loop)

```
replacena2 <- function(l) {
  stopifnot(is.numeric(l))
  indx <- which(is.na(l))
  l[is.na(l)] <- rowMeans(cbind(l[indx - 1], l[indx + 1]))
  l
}

replacena2(c(5, NA, 6, 2, 3, 5, 6, 4, NA, 2, NA, 5))
## [1] 5.0 5.5 6.0 2.0 3.0 5.0 6.0 4.0 3.0 2.0 3.5 5.0
```

Comment: Hi. First of all, thank you very much for your accurate answer. It is working like a charm. I have a question, Is it possible to return a vector of mixed elements? i.e. unmodified elements should stay integer/numeric, and calculated means can be double, it produces an output values without floating points (when unnecessary), which is: ## [1] 5 5.5 6 2 ...

Comment: An atomic vector can't contain two types of classes in R. Thus, the only way you can achieve your desired output is to convert it to character or factor class, but then it won't me a numeric class all together

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
library(zoo)
na.approx(v1)
[1] 5.0 5.5 6.0 2.0 3.0 5.0 6.0 4.0 3.0 2.0 3.5 5.0
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(5, NA, 6, 2, 3, 5, 6, 4, NA, 2, NA, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for(i in 1:length(xx)) if(is.na(xx[i]))
         xx[i] = ifelse(is.na(xx[i+1]),     xx[i-1],    (xx[i-1]+xx[i+1])/2)

xx
 [1] 5.0 5.5 6.0 2.0 3.0 5.0 6.0 4.0 3.0 2.0 3.5 5.0
```