# Replaing NAs with correlated values in rows

Tags: r

Hey All I have data frame with 5 Samples A,B,C,D,E.  and what I want to do is firstly search for a mirna which is overall  highly correlated with the miRNA having the missing value and taking a  value derived from that mirna ..  for example

miRNA-1 values: 1 2 3 NA 5
miRNA-2 values: 2 4 6 8 10
==> replace the missing value derived from the second miRNA by 4.

This is what I want to do for my data frame in R

Any help would be really appreciated :)

```
                                          A        B         C         D
hsa-miR-199a-3p, hsa-miR-199b-3p         NA   13.13892  5.533703  25.67405
hsa-miR-365a-3p, hsa-miR-365b-3p     15.70536   52.86558 18.467540 223.51424
hsa-miR-3689a-5p, hsa-miR-3689b-5p       NA   21.41597  5.964772        NA
hsa-miR-3689b-3p, hsa-miR-3689c     9.58696   44.56490 10.102051  13.26785
hsa-miR-4520a-5p, hsa-miR-4520b-5p 18.06865   28.06991        NA        NA
hsa-miR-516b-3p, hsa-miR-516a-3p         NA   10.77471  8.039662        NA
                                          E      
hsa-miR-199a-3p, hsa-miR-199b-3p         NA
hsa-miR-365a-3p, hsa-miR-365b-3p   31.93503
hsa-miR-3689a-5p, hsa-miR-3689b-5p 24.26073
hsa-miR-3689b-3p, hsa-miR-3689c          NA
hsa-miR-4520a-5p, hsa-miR-4520b-5p       NA
hsa-miR-516b-3p, hsa-miR-516a-3p         NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at this answer (esp Akrun's short cut from zoo)? I appreciate it's not quite what you want, but might give some leads. It is for means of neighbours in a row, so would suggest 1 2 3 NA 5 would be 4 (average 3 and 5).

[Replacing NA's in R numeric vectors with values calculated from neighbours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26754745/replacing-nas-in-r-numeric-vectors-with-values-calculated-from-neighbours?rq=1)

Trying to find a correlation between pairs with just 4 data points, as one is missing, is a challenge.