# Interpolate row-wise values of 0 between two columns with values >0 in R

Tags: r, data.table, interpolation, rowwise

I try to interpolate values of 0 between two values unequal to zero row-wise for the columns: 2018 to 2021 of a `data.table` in R. This is how a sample data `df1` would look like:

```
   ID string1 2018 2019 2020 2021 string2
1: a1      x2    3    3    0    4      si
2: a2      g3    5    5    4    0      q2
3: a3      n2   11    0    0    3      oq
4: a4      m3    3    0    9    8      mx
5: a5      2w    9    1    6    5      ix
6: a6     ps2    2    4    7    4      p2
7: a7     kg2    6    0    9    6      2q
```

For convenient reproducibility:

```
df1 = data.table(
  ID = c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6", "a7"),
  "string1" = c("x2", "g3", "n2", "m3", "2w", "ps2", "kg2"),
  "2018" = c(3,5,11,3,9,2,6),
  "2019" = c(3,5,0,0,1,4,0),
  "2020" = c(0,4,0,9,6,7,9),
  "2021" = c(4,0,3,8,5,4,6),
  "string2" = c("si", "q2", "oq", "mx", "ix", "p2", "2q"))
```

In `df1` there are cases with a zero between two numbers >0 (for example; row 1/column 2020, row 4/column 2019 or row 7 column 2019). I try to identify these cases and interpolate them with the neighbour columns (for example; row 1/column 2020: 3 + 4 =3.5).

Is there a way to deal with that? So far, I only found a method to replace all the zero values, but without the condition of being between two numbers >0.

I try to get such an output:

```
   ID string1 2018 2019 2020 2021 string2
1: a1      x2    3  3.0  3.5    4      si
2: a2      g3    5  5.0  4.0    0      q2
3: a3      n2   11  0.0  0.0    3      oq
4: a4      m3    3  6.0  9.0    8      mx
5: a5      2w    9  1.0  6.0    5      ix
6: a6     ps2    2  4.0  7.0    4      p2
7: a7     kg2    6  7.5  9.0    6      2q
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Row3 doesn't change because there are two zeros?

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26754745/680068

Comment: @zx8754 yes exactly, I only want to replace, if the zero value lies directly in between two values >0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it is an overkill, but here is a solution using reshaping twice:

```
melt(df1, measure.vars = patterns("^[0-9]+$")
     )[,value := fifelse(value == 0 &
                           shift(value, type = "lag", fill = 0) > 0 &
                           shift(value, type = "lead", fill = 0) > 0,
                         (shift(value, type = "lag") + shift(value, type = "lead")) / 2,
                         value), by = ID
       ][, dcast(.SD, ...~variable) ]

#    ID string1 string2 2018 2019 2020 2021
# 1: a1      x2      si    3  3.0  3.5    4
# 2: a2      g3      q2    5  5.0  4.0    0
# 3: a3      n2      oq   11  0.0  0.0    3
# 4: a4      m3      mx    3  6.0  9.0    8
# 5: a5      2w      ix    9  1.0  6.0    5
# 6: a6     ps2      p2    2  4.0  7.0    4
# 7: a7     kg2      2q    6  7.5  9.0    6
```

---

**Edit:** To fill in all NAs we can use *zoo::na.approx* or *zoo::na.spline*

```
cols <- grep("^[0-9]+$", names(df1), value = TRUE)

df1[, (cols) := transpose(lapply(transpose(.SD), function(i) zoo::na.approx(
  ifelse(i == 0, NA, i), na.rm = FALSE))),
  .SDcols = cols ]
# Using na.approx, notice 2nd row for 2021 is NA.
#    ID string1 2018     2019     2020 2021 string2
# 1: a1      x2    3 3.000000 3.500000    4      si
# 2: a2      g3    5 5.000000 4.000000   NA      q2
# 3: a3      n2   11 8.333333 5.666667    3      oq
# 4: a4      m3    3 6.000000 9.000000    8      mx
# 5: a5      2w    9 1.000000 6.000000    5      ix
# 6: a6     ps2    2 4.000000 7.000000    4      p2
# 7: a7     kg2    6 7.500000 9.000000    6      2q

# Using na.spline
#    ID string1 2018     2019     2020 2021 string2
# 1: a1      x2    3 3.000000 3.333333    4      si
# 2: a2      g3    5 5.000000 4.000000    2      q2
# 3: a3      n2   11 8.333333 5.666667    3      oq
# 4: a4      m3    3 7.333333 9.000000    8      mx
# 5: a5      2w    9 1.000000 6.000000    5      ix
# 6: a6     ps2    2 4.000000 7.000000    4      p2
# 7: a7     kg2    6 9.000000 9.000000    6      2q
```

Comment: Thanks, that also works perfectly in the sample dataset! Would there be a way without selecting the id.vars individually, since I have a data.table with many columns.

Comment: @fjurt see edit, we can select "measure" columns using *patterns*, so then the rest of the columns become *id.vars*.

Comment: do you know how to change your solution so that also two values with zeros next to each other would get linearly interpolated as it is the case in row 3 with the years 2019 and 2020? Thanks a lot:)

Comment: @fjurt see Edit, we can use zoo functions.

Comment: thanks a lot for your additional answer! Is there a way to only interpolate two zero values, but not more for example if there are three zero values next to each other?

Comment: @fjurt you can't keep changing the question, please ask as a new question.

Answer (score 5):

Function to interpolate zeros between two positive elements:

```
f <- function(vec){
  
  prev_val <- shift(vec, 1, fill = 0)
  next_val <- shift(vec, -1, fill = 0)
  
  fifelse(prev_val > 0 & next_val > 0 & vec == 0, (prev_val + next_val) / 2, vec)
}
```

Applying function to all rows for year columns:

```
year_cols <- names(df1)[grep("^[0-9]+$", names(df1))]
df1[, (year_cols) := transpose(lapply(transpose(.SD), f)), .SDcols = year_cols]
```

`transpose` is used because you want to do change on rows. Second use is to return it into column format.

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table` functions (and the original data.frame), this code (a bit cumbersome) should work:

```
for (i in c(2019,2020)){
  x = which(colnames(df1) == i)
  df1[,x] <- ifelse(c(df1[,.SD,.SDcols = x] == 0 & df1[,.SD,.SDcols = c(x-1)] > 0 & df1[,.SD,.SDcols = c(x+1)] > 0), 
                    rowMeans(df1[,.SD,.SDcols = c(x-1,x+1)]), unlist(df1[,.SD,.SDcols = x]))
}

> df1
   ID string1 2018 2019 2020 2021 string2
1: a1      x2    3  3.0  3.5    4      si
2: a2      g3    5  5.0  4.0    0      q2
3: a3      n2   11  0.0  0.0    3      oq
4: a4      m3    3  6.0  9.0    8      mx
5: a5      2w    9  1.0  6.0    5      ix
6: a6     ps2    2  4.0  7.0    4      p2
7: a7     kg2    6  7.5  9.0    6      2q
```

And here is a base R solution (using `data.frame` instead of `data.table` to generate the data):

```
for (i in c("X2019","X2020")){
  x = which(colnames(df1) == i)
  df1[,x] <- ifelse(df1[,x] == 0 & df1[,x-1] > 0 & df1[,x+1] > 0, rowMeans(df1[,c(x-1,x+1)]), df1[,x])
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your base R solution. If I run it, I get: j (the 2nd argument inside [...]) is a single symbol but column name 'x' is not found. Perhaps you intended DT[, ..x]. This difference to data.frame is deliberate and explained in FAQ 1.1.

Comment: This is because I load your dataset with `data.frame` and not `data.table`. Numerical name columns are not handled with `data.frame` so they are transformed to `X{numerical value}`. Hope this helps!

Comment: After verification, this is actually due to the fact that when you load the `data.table` package, data.table functions are used over base R functions like ` `[` `.

Comment: Is there an easy way to change the for loop without converting the data.table to a data.frame?

Comment: I edited my answer, tell me if it works! I'm pretty sure someone more advanced in `data.table` can make it shorter and better, but I tried to adapt from the base R solution.